# The probability that an electron occupies the fermi level at 0K

Tags: energy, electron, equation, fermi

I was trying to find the probability that an electron occupies the Fermi level at 0K.

Fermi function: {exp[(E-Ef)/kT] + 1}-1;
(k = 8.314 J/mol/K)

According to my calculations, the answer would be 0.5.

Is that answer correct?

Comment: that's not the Fermi-Dirac distribution, and I think that's what you mean when you say "Fermi function".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because off topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definition of the Fermi function is incorrect. Also, the derivation in your answer comes to the right result, 0.5, but from something wrong. I don't know how that happens. However,

> I was trying to find the probability that an electron occupies the Fermi level at 0K.

That's not really something you can "figure out". It's the **definition** of the Fermi level that it's exactly the energy level with a 50% population probability – at any temperature, including 0 K.

Answer (score 1):

The probability that an electron occupies the Fermi level at 0K is 0.5.

At 0K, when E = Ef the probability becomes equal to 0.5.

Fermi function:  f(E) = {exp[(E-Ef)/kT] + 1}-1; (k = 8.314 J/mol/K)

Moreover, At 0K,

when, E < Ef  ====> f(E) = 1

when, Ef < E  ====> f(E) = 0

Comment: it's not celar how you arrive at the 0.5. I mean, according to your formula, you have \$\lim_{T\to 0+} f(E(t)) \to e^{0/0}+1-1\$, and it's absolutely unclear how that would be 0.5, ever.